# RTX 4090 driver issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I recently installed an RTX 4090 GPU into my desktop. I am however struggling to get the nvidia drivers in ubuntu to work.

The usual "Additional Drivers" GUI menu simply says "No additional driver available". I tried installing the drivers via the terminal:

```
sudo apt intall nvidia-driver-520
```

But to no avail: The drivers do not seem to work, and running `nvidia-smi` gives the following message:

> ```
> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
> ```

I also tried installing `nvidia-driver-515` and `nvidia-driver-510`, with no results. I tried rebooting after each attempted driver install, and before installing a new set of drivers I always ran:

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia*; sudo apt autoremove
```

The driver installation GUI menu also never ended up displaying any available drivers.

Running `lspci` does not seem to find the actual model of the GPU. It simply outputs:

```
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2684 (reva1)

2d:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22ba (rev a1)
```

On windows everything runs flawlessly after updating the drivers, so the GPU is correctly installed in the system, and works.

Perhaps also worth noting is that I previously had an RTX 3080 installed, and all the drivers, as well as cuda worked without problems on my ubuntu system.

Any idea how to get the drivers for this GPU to work in ubuntu? I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

EDIT: I figured out secure-boot is at least part of the issue. With it disabled, things seem to work. This is however problematic for my dual boot with windows 11.

Comment: You need the latest drivers. Right now you can only get them from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us use the "New feature" branch

Comment: You can get 520.56.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 from the graphics-drivers ppa.  Probably avoids many update problems in the future.

Comment: How can I select a specific version? I see that the 'nvidia-driver-520-open' is the correct version, but when trying to install that with apt I get a bunch of dependency errors because all the dependent packages have newer versions in apt.

Comment: Some examples:

nvidia-driver-520-open : Depends: libnvidia-gl-520 (= 520.56.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 520.61.05-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: nvidia-dkms-520-open (<= 520.56.06-1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: nvidia-dkms-520-open (>= 520.56.06) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-520 (<= 520.56.06-1) but 520.61.05-0ubuntu1 is to be installed

Comment: Seems manually installing each dependency might work, but I am probably missing some faster way :p

Comment: After installing all the dependencies manually and then nvidia-driver-520-open, which has the version you suggested: the problems are not solved.

The system is still unable to detect the GPU.

Comment: Same goes for installing nvidia-driver-520=520.56.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

Comment: With secure-boot disabled things seem to work. Any way to get it to work without disabling that?

Comment: Search this site for signing kernel modules. You will probably need to do that each kernel/video driver update, but I've never done that, so can't say specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to check this page: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads.

After you select your arch, OS, etc select `deb (network)`. It will show a list of commands for you to install the driver and Cuda. Example:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

If you install this way you'll be able to upgrade with `apt update` later without issues. Usually there is no problem with package versions required by Nvidia and Ubuntu.

If you use tools like `nvcc` and they are not on your path make sure to add them, otherwise Ubuntu will prompt you to install it from some other non-nvidia package and that will cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with RTX 4080 card yesterday by downloading a '.run' file from the nVidia official website: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us.

The script asked to think twice installing driver not from the official repository of Ubuntu, but after the installation & reboot everything seems to work fine. Installed 525th driver still is not in the list of additional drivers, but everything works.

[image: Screenshot from nVidia settings]

Answer (score 0):

**Disabling the secure boot solved my problem too.**

Here are some steps:

1. Download the run file from nvidia official site https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us.
2. The command sudo telinit 3 will switch the current runlevel to runlevel 3, effectively terminating any running GUI sessions and switching to the CLI.

```bash
sudo telinit 3
```

Log in with your username and password.

3. Find your downloaded run file and run the command below.

```bash
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-xxx.run
```

Tada!